# How to convert casbah mongodb list to json in scala / play

Tags: scala, mongodb, playframework, casbah

I'm learning scala and mongodb at present and using the play! framework, so I'm making all sorts of mistakes as I get my head around things. Currently I have a scala object that returns a list of database objects returned from a mongodb query via casbah as follows;

```
object Alerts  {

   def list() : List[DBObject]= {

        val collection = MongoDatabase.collection;
        val query = MongoDBObject.empty
        val order = MongoDBObject("Issue Time:" -> -1)
        val list = collection.find(query).sort(order).toList
        list
   }
```

...
    }

Elsewhere in my code I wish to output the List of objects in Json - so I have;

```
  val currentAlerts = Alerts.list()
```

What I'd like to write is something like;

```
  val resultingJson = currentAlerts.toJson
```

But when I do this, I understandably get the following error;

```
  value toJson is not a member of List[com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBObject]
```

My question is - what's the right way to convert a List of com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBObject into Json for output?

EDIT:

For clarity, what I really want to do is the equivalent of

```
val listInJson = collection.find(query).sort(order).toJson
```

In the same way that I CAN write

```
val listAsString = collection.find(query).sort(order).toString
```

Comment: Did you try the `Json.toJson()` function ? (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaJson)

Comment: well why do you really need to convert the data as json ? It is stored as json in db (well bson really), do you really need the same back? i think you may just want to copy data into an object based on your desired structure and then serialize it into json...

Comment: I need to output it as JSON for a webservice to consume.

Comment: have you seen http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/util/JSON.html#serialize(java.lang.Object) ? I wonder if that can work for you...

Comment: @Roger, did you find an elegant solution?

Comment: Looks like reactivemongo is the new way in Play 2.1+ to do JSON ['coast-to-coast'](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaJsonTransformers). Here is the [sample project](https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-tailablecursor-demo)

Comment: Since the use case was asked, mine is to be able to provide 'pretty printing' of results. AFAIK, MongoDB APIs don't provide any pretty printing of a DBObject. So I'd like to convert to e.g. spray-json and pretty print there. But for raw JSON I'll simply use the DBObject's toString.

Answer (score 8):

You can try

```
com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(Alerts.list())
```

This should return a JSON array with your Alerts

Answer (score 5):

I have the following

```
def service() = Action {
 // connect
 val collection = MongoConnection()("someDB")("someCollection")
 // simply convert the result to a string, separating items with a comma
 // this string goes inside an "array", and it's ready to hit the road
 val json = "[%s]".format(
  collection.find(someQuery).toList.mkString(",")
 )

 Ok(json).as("application/json")
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I have what is a horrid solution as follows;

```
val currentAlerts = Alerts.list()

var jsonList : List[JsValue] = Nil

// Iterate over the DBObjects and use to String to convert each to JSON
// and then parse that back into the list so we can use toJson on it later.
// MAD, but works.

for (dbObject <- currentAlerts) {
    jsonList ::=  Json.parse(dbObject.toString)
}

val result = Json.toJson(jsonList)
Ok(result).as("application/json")
```

There must surely be a better way?

Comment: Hey Roger, did you ever find a better way to convert casbah DBObject to play's JsValue?

Comment: After getting `result`, how would you populate its key-value fields into a map?

Comment: This is actually a brilliant idea! If performance doesn't matter (e.g. in pretty-printing it doesn't) this is perfect. Thanks.