# efficient way to transform a playframework JsValue to a MongoDBObject

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, casbah

I'm receiving an JSON graph (payload) from the client, so at the web api I get a JsValue. I simply want to take that, decorate it with a couple of fields and store it in Mongo. Something like this:

```
case class Plan(_id: ObjectId, name: String, payload: JsValue)

{
  "_id" = 12345,
  "name" : "test model",
  "payload" : {a JSON graph}
}
```

From JsValue to database...

```
builder += "payload" -> JSON.parse(Json.stringify(model.payload))
```

From database back to a JsValue...

```
payload = Json.parse(dbo.as[MongoDBList]("payload").toString))
```

While it works to go from JsValue -> String -> MongoDBObject, I have two valid typed objects and I have to use an untyped intermediate format to go from one to another.

Comment: Very related, but ends up in same place as you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987071/how-to-convert-casbah-mongodb-list-to-json-in-scala-play

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store the graph as a string "payload", you can of course do that.

You may want to consider using [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/) instead of Casbah, along with [Play-ReactiveMongo](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo), which provides direct-to-JSON capability.  I have not used Play-ReactiveMongo.